# How to getElementById from getElementById search?

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

For some reason… when I `getElementById` and then try to search within that element for another `getElementById` it doesn't work.
The only way to find an ID from a `getElementById` is to use a `querySelector` why is this?

**Heads Up**
Yes, I know `querySelector` is a solution work around... But it doesn't answer the question of why `getElementById` > `getElementById` won't work.

`getElementById` > `getElementById` should work... it's pretty simple code. I'm not asking it to simulate gravity or anything.

**What I have:**

```js
document.getElementById("first").getElementById("second").innerHTML = "It works"
```

```html
<div id="first">
  <div id="second"></div>
</div>
```

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

```js
document.getElementById("first").querySelector("#second").innerHTML = "It works"
```

```html
<div id="first">
  <div id="second"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to do is illogical.

`id` attributes are required to be *unique* on a page. There shouldn't be 2 elements with the same `id`:

> `getElementById`: 
>
> Returns a reference to the element by its ID; the ID is a string which can be used to uniquely identify the element, found in the HTML id attribute. ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById))
>
> ---
>
> The `Element.id` property represents the element's identifier, reflecting the id global attribute.
>   It must be unique in a document, and is often used to retrieve the element using getElementById. Other common usages of id include using the element's ID as a selector when styling the document with CSS. ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id))

This means you can just ignore the parent `id`, and immediately get the child `id`'s element.

This is also why `getElementById` isn't available on anything but [`document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById). There is no reason to "scope" the search to some kind of parent element.

Answer (score 1):

> but it doesn't answer the question of why getElementById >
>   getElementById won't work.

Because as per [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

> Unlike some other similar methods, **getElementById is only available as
>   a method of the global document object**, and not available as a method
>   on all element objects in the DOM. Because ID values must be unique
>   throughout the entire document, there is no need for "local" versions
>   of the function.

And `document.getElementById("first")` **doesn't return the document**, it returns an `Element`

> **element**
>
> is a reference to an Element object, or null if an element with the
>   specified ID is not in the document.

[Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) doesn't have the `getElementById` method.